# Configuring Username and Password in PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, unix, psql

I have just reset my password in psql by editing my pg_hba.conf file to

```
local  all  all  trust
```

before changing it back to

```
local  all  all  md5
```

after. After doing this I tried to restart the psql server but I found that I have no access to any the server through the pg_ctl commands, for example if I try:

```
pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data restart
```

The reply is:

```
pg_ctl: could not open PID file 
"/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data/postmaster.pid": Permission denied
```

The only way that I'm able to open psql is with this command:

```
 psql -U postgres
```

Because if I try just 'psql', the response is the following:

```
psql: FATAL:  role "robertosullivan" does not exist
```

I need to find some way of connecting to psql with my username and my new password so that I can use psql with my app in Rails.

Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, "robertosullivan" does not exist. Which means that you have configured your PG with a user account that simply isn't there. Seems like the easiest way around this would be to create the user like so:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser robertosullivan -s
sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# \password your-password
```

Comment: I've followed these steps and the \password command prompted me for a new password. I set a new one, then typed psql but was told that robertosullivan does not exist. Any ideas?

Comment: or more specifically that 'database "robertosullivan" does not exist'.

Answer (score -1):

Below query might help you

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres -d postgres
```